# Overflow wraps text around div instead of scrolling

Tags: css

**Steps to reproduce:**

1: go to http://schultheiss.io/lc3-sim

2: click "STORE" button

3: click "EXECUTE" button

4: start typing

**What is supposed to happen:**

- the black terminal box acts like a text output. pressing the "enter" keystroke creates a new line. if enter isn't pressed, the text should stay on one line and create a scroll-bar overflow.

> 1 The quick brown fox ... jumped over the lazy dog (scroll bar for all this overflow)
> 2

**What is actually happening:**

- the black terminal box does not create an x-overflow and if you type a lot it forces a new line.

> 1 The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog
> 2

**What I have tried:**

```
#terminal {
    ...
    overflow: scroll;
    text-overflow: scroll; /* ? */
    ...
}
```

**What is happening:**

Each time a keystroke is pressed, `document.getElementByID("terminal").innerHTML += keystroke`, unless enter is pressed then `document.getElementByID("terminal").innerHTML += "<br>"`

How do I fix this with CSS? Full code at https://github.com/jschlth2/web-lc3

Edit: I simplified it down to an example in the HTML code below. If you run the code you'll see that it overflow-y's but does not overflow-x.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
    #terminal{ overflow: scroll; background-color: grey; width: 100px; height: 100px;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="terminal">
      1 The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog<br>2
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: it would be better a minimal (but complete, covering the entire issue) part of the code so the helpers can play with it and test; this github project is too big to check.

Comment: I will try to add more details that might help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried adding this and it seems to work for me.

```
#terminal {
   white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Add this CSS to DIV Class:

```
.wordwrap { 
   white-space: pre-wrap;      /* CSS3 */   
   white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* Firefox */    
   white-space: -pre-wrap;     /* Opera <7 */   
   white-space: -o-pre-wrap;   /* Opera 7 */    
   word-wrap: break-word;      /* IE */
}
```

[SEE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Shady_Alset/uxL3a68y/)

Comment: Is there a reason why this would work better than `white-space: nowrap`?

Comment: **nowrap:** Collapses whitespace as for normal, but suppresses line breaks (text wrapping) within text. **pre-wrap:** Sequences of whitespace are preserved. Lines are broken at newline characters, at `<br>` , and as necessary to fill line boxes..[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) _Never mind ! Choose what do you want :)_